# How to make an array of forms in html

Tags: php, html

I am developing a web page and in part of it I want to ask the user a series of yes/no questions. Taking into consideration that I want to display the second question in place of the first one after the user click next. For example:

I have 5 questions:
1- Are you happy?
2- Are you satisfied?
3- Are you hungry?
4- Are you tired?
5- Are you relaxed?

First I want to display the first question in the below form:

```
<div class="form-popup " id="Q" style="float:right">
        <div class="form-container text-center" >
            <header>
                <h1 style="color:green">Questions </h1>                   
            </header>

            <P>Are you happy?</p><br>
            
            <input type="radio" name="yes/no" required>
            <label >Yes</label>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="yes/no">
            <label >No</label><br><br><br>
        
            <button type="button" class="btn " >Next</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn " >Done</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want when the user answer this question and click Next, the second question is displayed automatically instead of the first. I want to automate it so that it would be easy for the admin to add, remove or edit any question?

Comment: where is the rest of the code? What have you tried? Do you need to store each answer somewhere - db, textfile etc?

Comment: you can make one form and hide all radio buttons excepting one you want to ask. and then if you press next button, you can hide current radio buttons and show next radio buttons and so on. finally at last question show submit button instead of next.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I didn't try anything yet other than hardcoding the form-popups and using javascript to close one and open the other one. The idea is that I want to read these questions from the database and automate the scenario that I explained above. Also, I don't need to store the answers

Comment: @George The problem is, first: the questions differ not the radio buttons. Second, I want to automate it so that it would be easy for the admin for example to remove one question or add one more and so on

Comment: "I want to automate it" is way too broad a scope for this site. This is a Q&A site for specific programming problems. Automating an entire process is anything but specific; it includes the following: picking the way to store your data, setting it up and creating processes for entering, validating, reading, displaying and removing data.

Comment: If you do not need to store the answers does that mean you process them immediately once only? How would you distinguish the answers given by one user compared to those by another? Presumably there are more than 5 questions and those shown are simple examples - can the user go back to correct an answer?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I neither process nor store these answers. The aim of these questions is to provoke the user to think about these aspects

Comment: ok - unusual I suppose. I guess then you don't mind if they do not participate as you will have no way to tell anyway.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I don't have problem in their participation, it is just a radio button. I have a problem in the mechanism of replacing a question with another one

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one piece of code that you perhaps may be able to continue with. Note that it lacks a lot of stuff, like taking care of (storing) the given answers, validating input, error checking, etc. But it will hopefully give you a hint on how it could be done. See it as a "start" for your solution. It needs a lot more in my opinion:

```
<?php
$question_ix = $_GET["q"] ?? 0;

$questions = array(
    "Are you happy?",
    "Are you satisfied?",
    "Are you hungry?",
    "Are you tired?",
    "Are you relaxed?"
);

if (($question_ix >= count($questions)) || ($question_ix < 0)) {
    echo "No more questions (or wrong question number)"; exit;
} else {
    $next_question = $question_ix + 1;
    $html = <<<EOD
    <html><head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-popup " id="Q" style="float:right">
            <div class="form-container text-center" >
                <header>
                    <h1 style="color:green">Questions </h1>                   
                </header>

                <p>{$questions[$question_ix]}</p><br>
                
                <input type="radio" name="yes/no" required>
                <label >Yes</label>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="yes/no">
                <label >No</label><br><br><br>

                <button  onclick="window.open('?q={$next_question}', '_self');" type="button" class="btn " >Next</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn " >Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    EOD;
    echo $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: could you explain this part: window.open('?q={$next_question}', '_self');

Comment: It's a small JavaScript code that simply opens the same page again, with the parameter `?q=2` (for second question). So if your file is named `yoursite.com/index.php` then the script redirects to `yoursite.com/index.php?q=2`

Comment: What if I don't want to reload the page. Is there a way to do it without reloading the page?

Comment: to do so without reloading the page will require either ajax or that all questions are written to a javascript variable on page load

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am trying to use ajax by using this function :function NextClick() {
    var self = window.location.href;
    console.log("Loading '#Q' from " + self);
    $('#Q').load(" #Q > *");
} Which is called whenever button Next is clicked but I keep getting error

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius this is the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: you do not need to use Ajax if there are no special requirements to process the user response and from what you shared it is impossiible for me to deduce what the prblem is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226858/discussion-between-heba-and-professor-abronsius).

Answer (score 0):

You can do through append and remove DOM element, the below are just a sample and you can tweak as your wish. If you want to update dynamic questions use ajax.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        i=0;
        $(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
            i++; // ensure new question is updated, you can remove this
            $(".form-container").remove();
            $("#Q").append('<div class="form-container text-center" ><header><h1 style="color:green">New Questions '+i+' </h1></header><P>Are you satisfied?</p><br><input type="radio" name="yes/no" required><label >Yes</label><input type="radio" name="yes/no"><label >No</label><br><br><br><button type="button" class="btn " >Next</button><button type="button" class="btn " >Done</button></div>');
        });
    });
</script>
```